# Создание n объектов в цикле

Tags: c++

Почему следующая программа не печатает "Created 10 objects" ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>

struct A {
     A() { counter++; }
    ~A() { counter--; }

    static inline std::size_t counter = 0;
};

std::size_t objects_number = 10;

int main() {
label:
    A a;
    if (A::counter < objects_number)
        goto label;

    std::cout << "Created " << objects_number << " objects" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Потому что локальные (стековые) обьекты создаются при входе в собственную процедуру, а уничтожаются при выходе из неё. Если хотите конкретного поведения - вызывайте конструктор явно.

Comment: @nick_n_a что такое "собственная процедура"?

Comment: Та, которая является владельцем обьекта. Если ни одна процедура не владеет обьектом - то будет другое поведение.

Comment: @nick_n_a, наверное, точнее будет сказать "в объемлющий блок", а не в процедуру.

Comment: @nick_n_a какая в этой программе "собственная процедура"? я не понимаю

Comment: возможно добавление блока исправит ситуацию, а возможно и нет, но тем не менее, всли выйти за пределы блока - вызовется деструктор, поэтому как с блоком, так и стелом процедуры - результат будет 0.

Comment: Ваше а принадлежит процедуре main. А ещё можно делать глобальную принадлежность, классовую, и динамическое обьявление.

Comment: @nick_n_a насколько я знаю, main - это функция

Comment: Хорошо, функция будет сказано более правильно, но это не менят суть вопроса. В данном случае конструктор может быть возван повторно лишь хитростями вроде 1)рекурсия 2)паралельный поток 3) явно.  Сам-по себе второй раз не вызовется.

Comment: Просто посмотрите, что происходит: https://ideone.com/RJVcc9

Comment: Как насчёт того, чтобы попробовать отладчик в пошаговом режиме?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Открываем [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/goto):

> The goto statement transfers control to the location specified by label. The goto statement must be in the same function as the label it is referring, it may appear before or after the label.
>
> **If transfer of control exits the scope of any automatic variables** (**e.g. by jumping backwards to a point before the declarations of such variables** or by jumping forward out of a compound statement where the variables are scoped), **the destructors are called for all variables whose scope was exited**, in the order opposite to the order of their construction.

То есть если с помощью goto выйти из области существования (scope) какой-либо автоматической переменной, то для этой переменной вызывается деструктор.

В том числе это происходит если выполнить прыжок назад, на строчку, которая находится выше, чем объявление переменной.

Answer (score 1):

Ваш пример - очередная демонстрация различий между концепциями *времени жизни* (lifetime) и *продолжительности хранения* (storage duration).

Ваш класс `A` обладает нетривиальным конструктором и деструктором. Это означает, что каждая итерация вашего goto-цикла прекращает время жизни вашего объекта `a` вызовом деструктора (как описано в цитате в ответе @HolyBlackCat) и затем снова начинает его время жизни вызовом конструктора. В каждый момент времени существует только один объект `a`, что и иллюстрируется значением вашего счетчика. При этом все эти объекты гарантированно занимают одно и то же положение в памяти - *продолжительность хранения* `a` все это время не прекращается. Она прекратится только при выходе из блока.

Доступ к `a` после вызова его деструктора приведет к неопределенному поведению. Используя менее тривиальный тип для демонстрации

```
  std::string *ptr = nullptr;

back:
  if (ptr != nullptr)
    std::cout << *ptr << std::endl; // <- Неопределенное поведение

  std::string a = "Hello World";

  if (ptr == nullptr)
  {
    ptr = &a;
    goto back;
  }
```

Но стоит вам избавиться от нетривиального деструктора, как время жизни объекта уже не будет прекращаться в момент обратного goto. Время жизни будет продолжаться вплоть до прекращения его продолжительности хранения (или до переинициализации)

```
  // В предположении, что `std::array<int, 3>` является тривиальным типом
  std::array<int, 3> *ptr = nullptr;

back:
  if (ptr != nullptr)
    std::cout << (*ptr)[1] << std::endl; // <- Поведение определено: выводит 2

  std::array<int, 3> a = { 1, 2, 3 };

  if (ptr == nullptr)
  {
    ptr = &a;
    goto back;
  }
```